# Failing to push dist directory updates to gh-pages branch using Yeoman

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, github-pages

I am getting the following error:

error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:joetamburro/westendstringband.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and merge the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

I am in a Yeoman Webapp and am trying to make a few minor updates and push them to my gh-pages branch. I developed as normal committing to my master branch in this case (small project I am working alone) and am getting that error when running: git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages. The thing is after checking out both my master and gh-pages branch and running git status everything is up to date??

Comment: Sounds like your branch is out of date (someone pushed new commits to master or somewhere upstream). You need to do a `git pull` to merge new commits, then commit the merge, and try to push again.

Answer (score 0):

I also used the subtree method for a while to push the my Yeoman dist folder to gh-pages. It causes headaches when the git endtips are misaligned, like you describe. The subtree method is a bit of a hack here.

There's a much better solution to this: [grunt-build-control](https://github.com/robwierzbowski/grunt-build-control) by Rob Wierzbowski. Takes 10 mins to install but works like a charm and the whole deploying of the build folder to remotes becomes automatic. Completely version controlled and painless.

Its now also mentioned in the [Yeoman wiki](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/wiki/Deployment) btw.